# Yii 2: Unable to find a class into the extension 'yii2-admin'

Tags: php, yii2

Extension's Github project: https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin

I'm using the advanced template of yii2, so I've `backend`, `frontend` and `common` folders all into an `advanced` folder.

the advanced folder itself is on the same level of `vendor` folder.

I've others extensions and all is working

Then I installed yii2-admin by composer

```
php composer.phar require mdmsoft/yii2-admin "*"
```

Installation worked well.

Into vendor folder I've now mdmsoft folder with `yii2-admin` subfolder into it.

This is the actual content of v`endor/yiisoft/extensions.php` (modified by composer installation, I haven't manually touched it)

```
<?php

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);

return array (
  'yiisoft/yii2-jui' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-jui',
    'version' => '2.0.0.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/jui' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-jui',
    ),
  ),
  'mdmsoft/yii2-admin' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'mdmsoft/yii2-admin',
    'version' => '1.0.2.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@mdm/admin' => $vendorDir . '/mdmsoft/yii2-admin',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I added this configurations to `common/config/main.php`

```
<?php
return [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // or use 'yii\rbac\PhpManager'
        ],
    ],
];
```

And these configs adedd to `backend/config/main.php`

```
'modules' => [
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
    ]
],
'components' => [

    'as access' => [
        'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
        'allowActions' => [
            'admin/*', // add or remove allowed actions to this list
        ]
    ],
],
```

(I omitted useless code in every code block)

I also have enabled pretty url. And it was working.

**Complete error stack**

```
2014-11-06 17:05:49 [127.0.0.1][-][-][error][ReflectionException] exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class mdm\admin\Module does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:408
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(408): ReflectionClass->__construct('mdm\\admin\\Modul...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(354): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('mdm\\admin\\Modul...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(147): yii\di\Container->build('mdm\\admin\\Modul...', Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('mdm\\admin\\Modul...', Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(354): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(511): yii\base\Module->getModule('admin')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(449): yii\base\Module->createController('admin/route')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(83): yii\base\Module->runAction('admin/route', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\backend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

**The problem**

If I open my backend at `/admin` I got this exception

> ReflectionException Class mdm\admin\Module does not exist

It's my first Yii2 app, so I've no idea of what's the problem and how to debug it.

**Edit 1**

I checked **C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\mdmsoft\yii2-admin\Module.php** and in its content there is the `Module` class definition

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
```

**EDIT 2**

My first error is that `asAccess` was put into `components` array. But It must be outside of it, at the same level

Now the error is changed:

```
Class mdm\admin\components\AccessControl does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** this is wrong

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
        'allowActions' => [
            // 'admin/*', // add or remove allowed actions to this list
        ]
    ],
],
```

It must be as here:

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
],
'as access' => [
    'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
    'allowActions' => [
        // 'admin/*', // add or remove allowed actions to this list
    ]
],
```

**Second**: you must run this command

```
php composer.phar require mdmsoft/yii2-admin "*"
```

from within the app root (`htdocs\advanced`), NOT from where you have executed the installation of yii (you were into `htdocs`). Only in this way to install yii2-admin into your app

**Third**: it's not true that console has not authManager ! if you have to use rbac, to simply do the default yii2 migration you must have it configured into console app. So my suggestione is: configure authManager into console, and other things into frontend and or backend where you need it

**Fourth**: you cannot admin frontend route from backend, so you need to enable this module even into frontend

Comment: This answer is incorrect I believe. https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin says that 'authManager' should be inside 'components', which is logical.

Answer (score 1):

*"I added this configurations to common/config/main.php"*
**NOTE: !!** Dont put at `common`, put in `frontend` or `backend`... console application has no user component and dont need access control.

Try adding this in `backend/config/main` right before `'modules'`

```
'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
'extensions' => require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php'),
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    ],
],
```

and I can't but assume that the whole thing has return in front, so the whole code is like:

```
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'extensions' => require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php'),
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', 
        ],
    ],
    'modules'=>[
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
        ],
    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
        'allowActions' => [
            'admin/*',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: sorry, nothing changed. I've not enabled cache component, but I was not the problem, of course. Also: I must put authManager config into common because a migration (included into the extesion) require it

Comment: @realtebo are all your relative paths correctly placed?

Comment: STOP: First error, I added 'asAccess' into components, but It must be outside, but now the error is different: 'Class mdm\admin\components\AccessControl does not exist'

Comment: I've found ALL the pieces for the right answer. So i'll publish it

Comment: the as_access should be inside the components array see here https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin